# WSO2EMM - App Management never returns list of users with App installed/not installed

Tags: android, mysql, linux, wso2-iot

I have wso2emm version 1.1.0 installed on a Linux CentOS 6.5 with a separate MySQL DB Server.
Everything seems to work fine: 
I can create users, send invites, have android agent installed and users' devices enrolled.
I can Upload Android App (I'm not testing iOS at the moment) and have them deployed on devices.
The problem arise when I connect to "Mobile Management Console":
WHen I click on the Tab "App Management" and then, on a particular App, this sends the following query to mysql

-- Connection Id: 47
-- User: wso2carbon
-- Host: localhost:34879
-- DB: WSO2_EMM_DB
-- Command: Query
-- Time: 208
-- State: Sending data

```
select out_table.id, out_table.user_id, out_table.device_id, out_table.received_data, devices.platform_id  from notifications as out_table , devices where out_table.`feature_code`= '502A' and out_table.`status`='R' and out_table.`tenant_id`=1 and out_table.`id` in (select MAX(inner_table.`id`) from notifications as inner_table where inner_table.`feature_code`= '502A' and inner_table.`status`='R' and out_table.device_id =inner_table.device_id)  and devices.id=out_table.device_id and devices.platform_id=1 and `received_data` not like '%renelco.hellorenelco%'
```

Then, no result are received by wso2emm (list nof roles or users) and the app hangs.

What's wrong with this ?

I tried several things like

- Killing mysql query/session
- Stopping/restarting MySQL.
- Stopping/Restarting wso2emm server
- Restarting the whole Linux server

But nothing has fixed the problem. It seems that something on the db server is blocking the query but 
I can't find what. Any help would be appreciated ...
Best Regards

Comment: See my answer here, the notifications table is growing over time, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38383815/114549

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a permanent solution, but it's a workaround that'll do the job until someone comes up with something better.

Back up the database files in EMM_HOME/repository/database on a regular basis; and then when the issue occurs, shut down the service and overwrite the WSO2EMM_DB.h2.db file with the latest backup made.

Something is causing the WSO2EMM_DB.h2.db file to get overinflated somehow. This happened to me tonight, and the bad file had a size of 49,016 KB, while the good file I backed up when the last changes were made has a size of 4,872 KB. That's a pretty significant difference.

**EDIT:** I've been running the server without making any changes to and keeping an eye on the WSO2EMM_DB.h2.db file. It seems to gain about 2 megabytes in size every hour. At first I thought it didn't gain size at a slow steady rate, rather all at once every hour, but after further experimentation I found it does in fact grow steadily.

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is an error in mysql script, you can verify by running h2 database. If it works, then it is an error caused by mysql script.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the answer. I know there is an error in the DB  creation script : column name "wifi_mac" in the table devices should be changed in "mac". But as for my problem. I don't have always the hang. I restored the whole thing (emm SW & DB), it worked during a while but suddenly, no possibilities to get any result when trying dealing with App Management. I can see the query in mysql workbench but it remains excuting undefinitely ... I don't think it's a problem with mysql. I will continue my investigation by restoring only EMM SW...

Comment: Definitely a Database problem. I restored the SW but nothing changed. Then, I restored the database and BINGO !!! I just have to find now if it's a real DB problem related to the structure of some table (unlikely), or a performance problem (more likely but more difficult to track). BTW, the problem was the same with H2, that's why I moved to mySQL, in order to have a better control on the Database server (H2 is embedded and that's not fine). I'm a bit new to all this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be fixed with EMM 2.0, available [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm/releases).