# WSo2 EMM Store doesn't allow Admin login

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When I try to log into the Store with the Admin account, it displays the following message:

**No Privileges to login

You do not have permission to login to this application. Please contact your administrator and request permission.**

I have checked and made sure the Admin account does indeed have the permissions it needs to log into the Store. I even created a new account and gave it all permissions, and it won't allow that account to log in either.

I even went as far as to dig into the database itself through MySQL, and best I can tell the proper permissions are there.

The last time this happened to me, I ended up unzipping a fresh copy of the EMM product and creating a brand new database for it because I couldn't figure out a solution. I tried unzipping a fresh copy of the EMM product, but running on the same database, it had no change in behavior. I have a database full of data I don't want to lose now, so I'd much rather find a fix than have to wipe it all out again!

WSo2 EMM 2.0.0
Windows Server 2012 R2
MySQL 5.5

**EDIT:** relevant logs:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-25 05:21:19,862]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2016-03-25 05:21:19,862-0500] 
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-25 05:21:19,862]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2016-03-25 05:21:19,0862] from IP address 10.200.201.108 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService 
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-25 05:21:19,909]  WARN {JAGGERY.controllers.acs:jag} -  User admin@carbon.super does not have permission to access the store application. Make sure the user has the store role.
```

Comment: have you done any config changes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.

Comment: @Aaron - should I use a different tag?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne - I have, but I don't think it matters because I tried unzipping a fresh copy of the EMM with no changes and it still behaved this way. This seems to be a database issue.

Comment: A different tag won't change the fact that this is a programming Q&A site, and you're asking for something along the lines of software product support.  This is decidedly **not** a programming question, and you should probably ask it on a site that specializes in WSO2.

Comment: @Aaron - That's odd, this hasn't been an issue before. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642663/wso2-emm-app-management-database-bug) of mine was up for two months without any complaints. Did I just get lucky, or is this something new?

Comment: I think it slipped through because this is such a low traffic tag (comparatively), and most of the mods don't notice.  But really, 49% of the questions in the WSO2 tag have gone "unanswered."  That suggests that the SO community really doesn't do a good job of answering these.  So there must be a better place to ask them.  And again, it's probably because most of them are not programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

The issue is specifically triggered by changing the password on the **admin** account to anything but "admin". Changing it back appears to rectify the issue.

Obviously this is a bug, as the admin account should be able to have its password changed and still be able to log into the Store. To be clear, there was never any issue logging into the Publisher; just the Store. Additionally, if the admin password was changed, no accounts could log into the Store at all, regardless of their permissions level.

I tested this with a fresh EMM pack, version 2.0.0 and 2.0.1, using the H2 and MySQL 5.5. In all cases the issue occurred.

A bug report has been filed on WSo2's JIRA board [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1295).

Comment: Did you try changing the username and password properties (there are multiple places) defined in <EMM>/repository/conf/app-manager.xml?

Comment: I did not. I changed the admin password via the EMM Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Is there are any configuration changes in your side.I got EMM 2.0.0 fresh pack and configure mysql 5.5.I tried to login emm store but It is working properly.

Comment: There are configuration changes, however I have tried it with a fresh EMM pack and the same issue occurs. That makes me think this is some kind of database issue.

It works fine with MySQL up to some point which I have yet to determine. I'm working on that now. Will update here with any results worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is raised in once we are trying change the password from the EMM console. But We can change the admin password from the /repository/conf/user-mgt.xml

```
<AdminUser>
     <UserName>admin</UserName>
     <Password>admin</Password>
</AdminUser>
```

and /repository/conf/app-manager.xml  admin credintials.